# Get number of selected items in android ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a multiselection ListView in my android app. What I need to know is how many items on that list I have selected.

Comment: FYI, don't write "solved" in the question title when you have a solution, instead, just mark the correct answer with a "tick" (can be found underneath the up/down vote, should be just an outline till you select it. This allows the site to properly manage the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.
getCheckedItemPositions() will create a SparceBooleanArray. So it is just to count the elements which are true in that array.

Example:

```
SparseBooleanArray positions = theListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
int counter = 0;
if (positions != null) {
    int length = positions.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (positions.get(positions.keyAt(i))) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use: `theListView.getCheckedItemIds().size();` Not sure if this will be faster (depends on internal implementation), but it might be a little clearer to other people looking at the code.

Comment: but the array created by getChekItemIds() does not get smaller when you uncheck an item.

Comment: actually, the code you posted had a bug since SparseBooleanArray.get() takes a key and is not necessarily the same as the index in the array.  The fix was a little too complicated to explain in a comment, so I just went ahead and edited your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use [getCheckedItemCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemCount%28%29) of ListView. This gives you directly an int.

Comment: Only available on API 11+ :/

Comment: I don't have any warnings or errors, but it's only available to API 11 and later, accepted answer is compatible with all Android versions

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `keyAt` followed by `get`, we can use `valueAt` directly.

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0, ei = checkedItemPositions.size(); i < ei; i++) {
    if (checkedItemPositions.valueAt(i)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```