# How to get the count of Listview item selection in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` which am setting that to my adapter. The `ListView` item contains two view elements which are `chekbox` and `TextView`.

I have given the `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)` for the `ListView`.

When i want to select one or more element, I want to get the count (based on selecting and deselecting).

I can't do this stuff in `onItemClickListener` of `ListView`.

So I have written the logic in BaseAdapter.

```
holder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count += 1;
        }
    });
```

But If i deselect the item then the value have to decrease. If iam having only one item in `ListView` then I can write

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
```

and get the value in Fragment. Just I get confused. Could someone help me?

Comment: Probably you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896294/get-number-of-selected-items-in-android-listview ?
using getCheckedItemCount() ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this.

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0, ei = checkedItemPositions.size(); i < ei; i++) {
    if (checkedItemPositions.valueAt(i)) {
        count++;
    }
} 
// use count as you wish
```

Make sure `count` is in a local (or block of the OnClickListener) scope so that every time you click a button or something, count gets reset and it recounts how many items are checked/unchecked.

Let me know if you have more question :)

Comment: How can i use this getListView().getCheckedItemPositions(); in my adapter?

Comment: instead of using getListView(), you could pass ListView object and directly access like `myListView.getCheckedItemPositions();`